# How to prevent object from flying towards camera when using Ray-cast in unity?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I got an unity project where object is meant to be moving with mouse cursor. The object moves fine, but when the object is still, it starts to float towards the camera that Ray-casts. I would like that the object doesn't float towards camera.
[image: Start Place]
[image: A while later from the start]

[image: Here is the code I am using]

I couldn't find any reason for objects behavior.

Comment: You are hitting the collider of that object so the hit is everytime closer to the camera ^^ just introduce a layer and ignore that layer in your raycast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this issue myself, and after getting on some Unity discords, someone else explained it to me:

**Why It Happens**

The reason this happens is because your Raycast is constantly casting a ray onto GameObjects in the scene, **including the GameObject you're moving**, so even though you're not moving the mouse, it's constantly casting through itself, moving itself closer and closer to the camera.

[image: Ray cast visualization]

You can solve this in two different ways. The first way is probably better.

**First Way**

You need to add a `LayerMask` to your entire movable surface that your object can move on. So if you have a ping pong paddle and a table, add a LayerMask of `Movable` onto the ping pong table surface.

**Then, make sure that your 3D object DOES NOT have that LayerMask.**

Then, in your Script, add a `public LayerMask` variable, and add it to your Raycast:

```
public LayerMask layerMask;

private void Update() {
    Ray rayOrigin = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin, out RaycastHit hit, layerMask)) {
        transform.position = hit.point;
    }
}
```

To explain this, the `LayerMask` forces the Raycast to only cast on a specific Layer of gameObjects, so it's essentially ignoring your movable 3D object.

**Second Way**

Another way is to force the `Y` coordinate of `transform.position` to stay at a specific level, but that's only really useful if you don't require vertical movement, so take this with a grain of salt.

According to [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html), `RaycastHit.point` is a Vector3, so you can just use the `X` and `Z` coordinates:

```
Ray rayOrigin = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin, out RaycastHit hit)) {
    transform.position = new Vector3(hit.point.x, transform.position.y, hit.point.z);
}
```

However, this doesn't really solve the underlying issue, so it's probably better to just use the first method.

Comment: Hey @Heebo, my first answer to this question was bad advice. I updated it to a new method that actually solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite a novice who's had issues with gameobjects following cursors myself.
But could you try freezing the Y position in the Rigidbody and ensure gravity is unchecked?

More of a workaround if it even works.

Also I believe it's better practice to use rigidbody.position than transform.position. Try this:

```
public Rigidbody rigidbody;

void Update()
{
rigidbody.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, -Camera.main.transform.position.z));
}
```

Comment: What if this object isn't a Rigidbody at all?

Comment: I would recommend adding Rigidbody component if working with physics, also rigidbody.position returns more accurately than transform.position. (I THINK, like I already noted I'm a novice^^)

Comment: @derhugo someone much smarter than me explained that it's best practice to always add rigidbody to anything that collides that isn't static

Comment: the position is as accurate. You are right about the `rigidbody.position` in case there actually **is** a `Rigidbody` .. in that case `transform.position` shouldn't be used as it can lead to unrealistic movement and break physics and collision detection. Also you need at least one RB involved for collision detection yes. It would still be enough though if this is the case on the ball

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is when you send a ray and you get a hit result using hit.point it gives the exact location of the tris on the object it is hitting. Lets say the object is centered in the world (Vector3.zero). Ray is hitting a tris that is different than the position zero. Just because the object is in x:0y:0z:0 doesnt mean all the tris on the object is located at the same coordinates.

You get the coordinates of the hit.point, they are probably closer than the object center position, therefore the object is updating its center position to the hit.point location. And it does that every frame moving the object closer to camera.

You might want to try sending a ray from screen to world position. You can use custom vector length which would help to keep the object in the same depth you like.

[Unity Docs Screen to World](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html)